# How to fix this error, Scaffold-DBContext : Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I am trying to run a command on Nuget using this below and getting an error gets thrown as "Scaffold-DBContext : Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"

```
Scaffold-DBContext "Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Catalog=eNtsaRegistration;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

I have already all necessary libraries, just i am getting this error and dont know how to fix it. Basically i want to create Dbcontext inside my project folder without using DbEntities. Please assist me mates to improve this logic better.